# Getting DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG error

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, dns, window, wifi

I have couple of wifi connections out of which one works fine whereas the other one only works for some of the websites and services like google.com & skype. Browsing rest of many websites usually gives me that error:

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG
```

I rarely get following errors as well:

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

Another very strange thing that I experienced is that repeatedly refreshing a page often opens it whereas it doesn't apply at every web page.

I found many solutions as an outcome of long searches at Google & Stack Overflow but none of these worked. This is not a browser particular issue as getting the same issue on all the browsers I've (i.e. Chrome, Mozilla & IE). I'm getting the same issue at my official machine with Ubuntu OS & personal machine with Win10 OS. Meanwhile I've no problem with web surfing at my mobile and other PCs connected with the same connection.

Detailed information about the real cause and solution (preferably for both Ubuntu & Win10) will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**For Ubuntu**

These errors indicate that there is some problem with DNS.

- check `cat /etc/resolv.conf` for your DNS settings.
- And add following name server in  `/etc/resolv.conf` for temporary or in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` for permanent

> ```
> nameserver 8.8.8.8
> nameserver 8.8.4.4
> ```

- To add these two name server address in `resolv.conf`

  - run command `sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf`
  - Copy above two line of nameserver paste on last line of `resolv.conf`
  - Ctrl+S to save.
- Note: If you add name server only `/etc/resolv.conf` then when computer is restarted then `/etc/resolv.conf` is in previous stage.
  So, to store these nameservers permanently, use following method :

  - run command `sudo gedit /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`
  - Copy above two lines of nameserver and paste on last line of `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`
  - Ctrl+S to save.
- Re-connect internet connection

More Detail On https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Debugging#DNS_Servers

**For Windows:**

- Add these DNS ip on network configuration
- Tutorial to add DNS in windows is here
  https://www.opennicproject.org/configure-your-dns/how-to-change-dns-servers-in-windows-7/
- Re-connect internet connection

Comment: I actually had some issues with OpenVPN in Ubuntu and doing this resolved it. I could't open some specific websites like YouTube, Facebook, etc(they're blocked in this country) but I could still open some others.

Answer (score 3):

Open your cmd and put below two commands

**ipconfig /release**

**ipconfig /renew**

Now open run and type ncpa.cpl and press enter . 
after that on your ipv4 settings you to set below dns on there

**8.8.8.8**

**8.8.4.4**

**Tuitorial  :** https://tricksmotion.com/how-to-fix-dns_probe_finished_bad_config-problem-in-google-chrome-tricksmotion/

Answer (score 3):

I am using kali linux. I came across so many ways which all failed to work but one. 
In the terminal, type:-

```
sudo apt-get purge resolvconf
```

A GUI appears, click okay. Reboot your machine. You should be able to access the internet once it starts.